# Android Socket continue reading till a specific String sequence

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedreader

I want to read from a socket till a specific String sequence like `<END>`. The problem is the server sometimes returns me the data in chunks that is when the text (JSON) is too long to be sent in packets. I want to make a logic where the socket keeps appending a String Builder until the stream ends at `<END>` and after that continue appending another message.

```
InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inr);

byte[] resultBuff = new byte[0];
byte[] buff = new byte[99999];
int k;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((k = in .read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > -1) {
 byte[] tbuff = new byte[resultBuff.length + k]; // temp buffer size = bytes already read + bytes last read
 System.arraycopy(resultBuff, 0, tbuff, 0, resultBuff.length); // copy previous bytes
 System.arraycopy(buff, 0, tbuff, resultBuff.length, k); // copy current lot
 resultBuff = tbuff; // call the temp buffer as your result buff
 System.out.println(resultBuff.length + " bytes read.");
 String s = new String(resultBuff);


 sb.append(s);

 if (s.endsWith(DELIMITER)) {

  String response = sb.toString().replace(DELIMITER, "").replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

  System.out.println(response);

  if (listener != null) {
   listener.onMessageReceived(params[0], response);

  } else {
   Log.e(TAG, "Response :: listener.onMessageReceived null ");
  }
  resultBuff = new byte[0];
  sb = new StringBuilder();
 } else {
  sb.append(s);

 }


}
```

The goal here is to keep the while loop running so that the socket can keep reading whenever something comes in stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
String str = "";
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
for(int r = 0; (r = is.read(b))!=-1;){
    str += new String(b,0,r);
    if(str.contains(DELIMITER)){
        String message = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(DELIMITER));
        str = str.substring(str.indexOf(DELIMITER)+DELIMITER.length());
        //process message.
    }
}
if(!str.isEmpty()){
    //the JSON object was sent in a single chunk, porcess it
}
```

What this does is to store all the data read from the `InputStream` into the `str` `String` and when the `str` contains the `DELIMITER` it will extract the message from the `str` so it can be processed. This will fail if the buffer contains more then one message. You can use `String[] messages = str.split(DELIMITER)` to deal with that.

A better solution will be to use a `Scanner`, here is an example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
sc.useDelimiter(DELIMITER);
while(sc.hasNext()){
    String message = sc.next();
    // process message.
}
```

Comment: both solutions does not work at all especially with scanner.

Comment: @H.T The `useDelimiter(...)` accepts a regex, if your `DELIMITER` contains special regex characters, you will have to escape them. Try `sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.quote(DELIMITER))`

Comment: My delimiter is a string value <END> Unfortunately the message returned is empty.

Comment: using useDelimiter("\\s*<END>\\s*") did the trick how ever long messages are not being read fully. Does not solve the problem

Comment: @H.T The `Scanner` method will fail if the server sends the message in a single chunk and it doesn't close the connection when it is done. I've edited the first example to deal with cases when the message is sent in a single chunk.